# SetContentView(objectOfClass) vs SetContentView(LayoutXMLFile)

Tags: java, android

I am writing an application in Java for android that draws filled circle shapes on canvas.

I have written a draw circles class to handle events and the actual drawing of the circles:

public class drawCircles extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

```
float x, y;

Paint paint = new Paint();
PointF pointf = new PointF();
ArrayList<PointF> locations = new ArrayList<PointF>();


public drawCircles(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    pointf = new PointF(x, y);
    locations.add(pointf);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;

    switch(n)
    {
        case 1:
            paint.setColor(GREEN);
            break;
        case 2:
            paint.setColor(RED);
            break;
        case 3:
            paint.setColor(YELLOW);
            break;
        case 4:
            paint.setColor(BLUE);
            break;
    }

    int i=0;
    while(i < locations.size())
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(locations.get(i).x,locations.get(i).y,50, paint);
        i = i + 1;
    }

}
```

}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawCircles draw = new drawCircles(this);
    setContentView(draw);
}
```

}

My application  works just fine as long as the setContentView method in the onCreate() method for the main activity is set to an object of the drawCircles class

My question, is when you point setContentView at an instance of a class like this, is it possible to customise the layout? I want to add widgets for paint brush size etc.

My first thought was to set the content view to a customised xml file then call methods from the drawCircle class where appropriate however if I am understanding the reading I have done correctly, it is not possible to call the onDraw() method from a class that doesn't extend a view, so I can't call them from my main class which extends an activity class for backwards compatibility.

It has occured to me that it may be possible to assign the drawCircles class a particular layout.xml file but I haven't been able to find any cases where this has been done.

Any advise is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want to a view either way.  The two functions run the same code-  the one that takes a layout identifier just inflates the layout into a View, then calls setContentView on the result.

Its also quite possible to put a custom view in xml, in which case its onDraw will be called.  I think you don't quite understand how xml inflation works, which makes it difficult to figure out how to help you.

Also, you would never call onDraw directly.  Its called by the framework when a view has an invalid area.

Comment: Thanks for responding my issue is I don't know how to customise my view unless setContentView is pointed at a layout xml file

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, let see some custom libraries like custom dialog, calendar,... they define many case for properties.

In xml, just choose property value then the custom view class will do every things.

The first thing you need is learn more about custom view, collect attribute, set conditions...
 Let see some samples:

```
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html
http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/
```